# Detect if Specific words found .Net

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Hello I try to find specific words of that represent a number

Ex:
 - Number "One" in RichTextBox

My code :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim str As String = RichTextBox1.Text
    Dim strarr() As String
    strarr = str.Split(" "c)
    For Each s As String In strarr

        Dim words() As String = s.ToLower.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If words.Count(Function(w) RichTextBox2.Text.Contains(w)) > 0 Then

            Label1.Text = s
            Label1.Text = "Founded"
        Else
            Label1.Text = "not founded, if we find it, we will type it , in label1"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

RichTextBox2 = list of my words (1 - 5) numbers.
RichTextBox1 = which i focus on it.

The problem is when I type in RichTextBox1.text
`hello i want type numbers, on`
it will detect "on" as (one). This not my purpose.

[explaining By picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6eZj.png)

Comment: I think in kinda get what you want, but just to be sure: you want to write in a box, click a button and then all the numbers found in the first box are re-written in the second box?

Comment: Don't use `Contain()`, use `Equals()`, maybe adding `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. `Regex.Matches` will be probably better, if you also want to know how many *words* you *found* that match the criteria and their position inside the text.

Comment: First, get your output straight. It will never show what was found (what is inside `string s`), because it gets overwritten by the text `Founded`. You'll see that it will output something different than you think it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may work better:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' first remove any previous Label1 text
    Label1.Text = ""

    ' cleanup the RichTextBox2 text by replacing any whitespace or non-word character by a single space character
    ' make it all lowercase and trim off the spaces left and right
    Dim keyText As String = (Regex.Replace(RichTextBox2.Text, "[\s\W]+", " ")).ToLower().Trim()
    ' next, split it into an array of keywords
    Dim keyWords As String() = keyText.Split(" "c)

    ' get the user input and prepare it for splitting into words like we did with the RichTextBox2 text
    Dim input As String = (Regex.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "[\s\W]+", " ")).ToLower().Trim()

    ' split the cleaned-up input string into words and check if they can be found in the keyWords array
    ' if we do find them, we want only list them once so collect them first in a List
    Dim wordsFound As New List(Of String)
    For Each word As String In input.Split(" "c)
        If keyWords.Contains(word.ToLower()) Then
            If Not (wordsFound.Contains(word)) Then
                wordsFound.Add(word)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' finally, add the result to the label
    Label1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, wordsFound)
End Sub
```

[image: demo]

Comment: You Are awesome, this what specific i wanted

Big thanks, With Grate Solution from best Thread Ever in the world "StackoverFlow", Helped many people.